# How to apply the same dynamic route to multiple pages

Tags: next.js

I have a collection component that is mapped on the home page ('/') and on the illustrations page ('/illustrations'). This component handles different data that corresponds to different collections. On the illustrations page, I have a dynamic route [collectionId].js which maps the images that correspond to the specific collection. When I'm on the /illustrations route and click one of the collections, the corresponding images are correctly mapped to the page. However, when I am on the / route and click the collection, the application breaks, and I am presented with the following error [image: see image here]I need to be able to have the correct images mapped when the user clicks the "collection" component on the home page.

```
// Collection Component:
    export default function Collection({title, description, collection, id }) {
      return (
        <Link href={`/illustrations/${id}`}>
          <div className='border rounded-sm border-[#222222] p-12 mv:px-6 md:px-12 outline-zinc-400 flex flex-col justify-between items-start cursor-pointer hover:shadow-black transition-all ease-in 0.75s'>
            <span className='flex items-center mb-4'>
              <div className='w-0.75 h-5 bg-secondary'></div>
              <p className='ml-2'>{title}</p>
            </span>
            <h3 className='text-3xl mb-4'>{collection}</h3>
            <div className='flex flex-col items-start'>
              <p className='mb-12 text-left'>{description}</p>
              <ArrowLink title='Visit' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      )
    }

// [collectionid.js]
    export default function Collection() {
      const router = useRouter()
    
      const collectionID = router.query.collectionID
    
      const collection = getCollectionById(collectionID)  
    
      // if (!collection) {
      //   alert('Page does not exist')
      // }
    
      return (
        <div className='grid mv:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 px-24 gap-x-16 gap-y-52 place-items-center'>
          {collection.imageData.map((image, index) => {
            return (
              <Link
                href='#'
                key={index}
                className='relative cursor-pointer h-full flex items-center hover:border hover:border-[#DCDCDC] hover:shadow-lg ease-in duration-150'
              >
                <Image
                  src={image.image}
                  alt={`Vector ${image.alt} illustration`}
                />
                <p className='whitespace-nowrap text-center px-6 py-2 bg-white text-black border border-black absolute -bottom-24 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2'>
                  Preview image
                </p>
              </Link>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: what does `getCollectionById` do?